# Bluetooth low energy Security

Tags: c#, security, bluetooth-lowenergy

while facing problems with a C# BLE connection I've digged deeper in the Bluetooth low energy Connection part.
Here I'm not shure if I understand this part 100%.

In my case I want to connect to a device that requires bonding to start datatransfer otherwise I reiceive the right amount of Bytes but only zeros.
My application somtimes works and I receive the expected values, sometimes I only receive zeros and sometimes I get an error "System.ArgumentException" in mscorlib.dll and my app crashes.
Before I start Changing my Code I want to be shure that I understand the Connection part right.
With BLE I can do bonding, pairing and connect.
Bonding means in general the same a pairing. Encrytion keys are exchanged and in case of bonding, the keys are saved permanent and are resused for future sessions between two specific devices.
Pairing keys are only valid for one session.
https://eewiki.net/display/Wireless/A+Basic+Introduction+to+BLE+Security
Based on this link, Bluetooth uses an AES suit.
So for me, these two Options are clear( of course in case that I understood them correct).
So now I've read that it is possible to get a connection without bonding or pairing since a Windows Creators update.
I understand that there is no key exchange and based on my knowledge on AES can't be used. 
Is a communication with using just a Connection between two devices really completely unsecure or am I missing something?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, without pairing/bonding the BLE link is unencrypted and all data transferred back and forth can be read easily using a sniffer. On the other hand, if pairing/bonding is used, all data transferred back and forth is encrypted and cannot be read using a sniffer unless the encryption key is used at the sniffer end as well.

For more information, please see [Bluetooth Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification), Version 5.0, Vol 3, Part H, section C.2 (Authentication and Encryption).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. If this answers your question then it would be helpful for others if you mark this as correct.